# Attempting to add an external user but receiving the following error (Error 403: org_Internal)

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

One of my colleagues has a Python script for one of our projects that accesses files in Google Drive and edits them (renaming, copying, sharing/unsharing). The application requires OAuth2 authentication as it will edit on behalf of the user.

Here's the issue. We have two domains, the project is sitting on our main domain, and our second domain is used for secondary employees. Both domains are google gsuite domains. We're trying to get permissions for one of our employees on the second domain to have access (and authenticate)to the project, but when they follow the OAuth link it gives the Error 403: org_internal error.

Our two restrictions are that the project must remain Internal, and we cannot recreate that employee's account on our main domain. I'm assuming that makes our predicament unsolvable but I'm counting on the fact I've missed something obvious.

Steps I have taken:

Added the second domain to the Authorized domains in OAuth consent screen
Added the second domain to the Domain Verification page
Added users from the second domain in IAM with editor permissions for the project

Comment: This is because it's set to internal. There's no way around this aside from migration, or setting the user up an account on the other domain for the sole purpose of using the application.

Comment: Thanks @RafaGuillermo, I had an inkling this was the case